# How much memory is my iphone app using (from Simulator)

Tags: iphone, memory-management, instruments

I know this has something to do with Instruments, but well it's kind of confusing and searching for Instruments on Google doesn't help much.

I'd like to know how well my app runs, like how much memory it uses. I just don't know where to find something like:
"As close as we can tell from the simulator you'll app will currently be using xx MBs of RAM on a real iphone device."

I need help on how to get this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't test your memory usage in the simulator for a number of reasons, some of which are:

- The simulator is running on your computer, not the phone, so the maximum amount of memory is the same as the amount of ram you have installed in your Mac.
- The simulator, and your app when build with the simulator SDK, do not use the same libraries as they would on the device, and as a result, could use a different amount of memory.

However, if you can run on a device, you should use the Memory Monitor and Object Allocations instruments in Instruments to monitor your memory usage.

Comment: Well will the simulator give close results, I guess I just want to know if I'm not using like 100s MB.

Comment: It's unpredictable what the simulator will report in terms of memory usage. That's why you shouldn't do performance profiling in the simualtor. Use the device for that stuff. The simulator is great for UI testing, interaction and flow etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Run/With Performance Tools/Object Allocations. The graphs will show you the memory used.

And then you check the box "Created and Still Living" to know what objects are in memory.